# OpenVZ Reboot failed for Ubuntu 12.04 32bit container

Tags: openvz, containers

The container on OpenVZ server was setup using the template Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit and it was successful.The container fails to load when reboot operation is preformed.Re-installation of the container will only make the server back online.The following error log happens when the container is started after shutdown.

```
[root@openvz ~]# vzctl start 4879
Starting container...
Unmounting file system at /vz/root/4879
--- lsof /vz/root/4879 output ---
Error in print_output (ploop.c:945): Command lsof exited with status 1
Error in do_umount (ploop.c:983): Failed to umount /vz/root/4879: Device or resource busy
Failed to umount image: Error in do_umount (ploop.c:983): Failed to umount /vz/root/4879: Device or resource busy [22]
Adding IP address(es): 12.34.56.78
/bin/bash: line 535: /etc/network/interfaces: Read-only file system
/bin/bash: line 567: /etc/network/interfaces: Read-only file system
/bin/bash: line 574: /etc/network/interfaces: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/network/interfaces.bak': Read-only file system
/bin/bash: line 598: /etc/network/interfaces.bak: Read-only file system
mv: cannot stat `/etc/network/interfaces.bak': No such file or directory
Setting CPU limit: 100
Setting CPU units: 1000
Setting CPUs: 1
/bin/bash: line 122: /etc/init/console.conf: Read-only file system
/bin/bash: line 122: /etc/init/tty2.conf: Read-only file system
/bin/cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/hosts.21': Read-only file system
 ERROR: Can't copy file /etc/hosts
Container start in progress...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved it

The container was having an IP address which was used earlier for another container.When the previous container was terminated the private area of the container was not removed.So after installing the new container it loaded the new private area.But after reboot the container got confused to load the correct configuration and it must have loaded the private area of the old container.

So deleting the old private area is the solution,
Here are the actions that were took to resolve this issue.

```
[root@openvz /]#vzlist -a| grep 12.34.56.78
     4870         mounted      12.34.56.78   host20305.server.com
     4879         28 running   12.34.56.78   host20305.server.com
```

Here you can clearly see that virtual machine `4870` belongs to the old container,which is needed to be destroyed.Now perform the following commands.

```
[root@openvz /]# vzctl destroy 4870
Container is currently mounted (umount first)
[root@openvz /]# vzctl umount 4870
Unmounting file system at /vz/root/4870
--- lsof /vz/root/4870 output ---
Error in print_output (ploop.c:945): Command lsof exited with status 1
Error in do_umount (ploop.c:983): Failed to umount /vz/root/4870: Device or resource busy
Failed to umount image: Error in do_umount (ploop.c:983): Failed to umount /vz/root/4870: Device or resource busy [22]
[root@openvz /]# umount -l /vz/root/4870
[root@openvz /]# vzctl destroy 4870
Destroying container private area: /vz/private/4870
Container private area was destroyed
```

Now check the status of the container.

```
[root@openvz /]#vzlist -a| grep 12.34.56.78
     4879         28 running   12.34.56.78   host20305.server.com
```